# Steaming heavy cream?

Tags: steamed-milk, latte

Is there any *good way* to steam heavy cream to make a latte? I've occasionally had customers request heavy cream for the milk in their latte, and the result is always a mess. The cream resists the little jets of steam and splatters all over your hands and the countertop and the espresso machine. And it's just so hard to get any air in there that the whole pitcher screams out in pain the whole time, suggesting that it's scalding.

My only thought is to try to argue with the customer to allow me to put just a little milk in there so I can aerate it properly. Or, maybe dropping the espresso into the cold cream and using *that* water to thin out the cream?

Does anyone have a magic solution?

Comment: I don't think I have cream to try now, but what if you used an electric whisk while steaming? That already works to aerate cold cream so it'd be interesting to test while steaming.

Comment: @JJJ That's an interesting idea and might just work. I wonder if it can be scaled back to lower tech, tho. Like, shaking the carton first to get some bubbles started, or a little surface agitation with a bar spoon or a tiny whisk. I doubt I could get an electric whisk ordered at work, but a tiny manual whisk with a long handle -- if they exist -- that's something I could argue for. ... It'd be useful for white mocha and caramel sauce too.